# ACS Smart Card Reader

Tags: sdk, nfc, smartcard

I would like to know where can I download the ACR122U SDK tool. This is a contactless smart card reader. This is because, I have purchased the NFC card reader but without the software. So if there is any other tools that can actually reads the ACR122U, other than the original sdk itself, do let me know. I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://acs.com.hk/drivers/eng/API_ACR122U.pdf is all you need. The communication uses standard CCID + PC/SC, so you just need to know what you are doing.

Comment: How about providing some more information for those that don't know what they are doing they might learn!